# Fluent API: Reference types take values from eachother

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper, fluent-interface

I'm currently writing a grid for MVC that is an HtmlHelper extension and I'm running into a strange problem with it.

First of all, this is the code I'm using the construct the grid:

```
RenderedOutput = HtmlHelper.GridFor(Model)
.WithColumns(column =>
{
    column.Bind(x => x.Name)
        .WithCss("inline");
    column.Bind(x => x.Age)
        .WithCss("inline fixed right");
})
.Render();
```

Now, the entire fluent API is built up by using interfaces, to make the copy-past work a bit smaller, I do not post the interfaces here but I'll post the implementation:

First of all, the HtmlHelper:

```
public static IGridBuilder<TEntity> GridFor<TModel, TEntity>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
    IEnumerable<TEntity> dataSource)
{
    return new GridBuilder<TEntity>(htmlHelper, dataSource);
}
```

So this return a GridBuilder, of which the implementation is here:

```
#region Constructors

public GridBuilder(HtmlHelper helper, IEnumerable<TModel> data)
{
    HtmlHelper = helper;
    DataSource = data;

    ColumnBuilders = new List<IColumnBuilder<TModel>>();
}

#endregion

#region Properties

private string Id { get; set; }

#endregion

#region IGridBuilder Members

public IList<IColumnBuilder<TModel>> ColumnBuilders { get; protected set; }

public IEnumerable<TModel> DataSource { get; private set; }

public HtmlHelper HtmlHelper { get; private set; }

public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithId(string id)
{
    Id = id;
    return this;
}

public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IColumnBuilder<TModel>> bindAllColumns)
{
    bindAllColumns(new ColumnBuilder<TModel>(this));

    return this;
}

public HtmlString Render()
{
    var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    var headerMember = new TagBuilder("div");
    headerMember.MergeAttribute("class", "gridHolder v-scroll");

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
    {
        headerMember.GenerateId(Id);
    }

    outputBuilder.AppendLine(headerMember.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

    // Process all the available columns.
    var rowBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
    rowBuilder.MergeAttribute("class", "row");
    outputBuilder.AppendLine(rowBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));

    foreach (var column in ColumnBuilders)
    {
        var columnBuilder = new TagBuilder("div");
        outputBuilder.AppendLine(columnBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.StartTag));
        outputBuilder.AppendLine(columnBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));
    }

    outputBuilder.AppendLine(rowBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

    outputBuilder.AppendLine(headerMember.ToString(TagRenderMode.EndTag));

    return new HtmlString(outputBuilder.ToString());
}

#endregion
```

}

The GridBuilder takes an Action of IColumnBuilder to build the column, so here it is:

```
public class ColumnBuilder<TModel> : IColumnBuilder<TModel>
{
    #region Constructors

    public ColumnBuilder(IGridBuilder<TModel> gridBuilder)
    {
        GridBuilderReference = gridBuilder;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IColumnBuilder Members

    public IGridBuilder<TModel> GridBuilderReference { get; private set; }

    public string CssClass { get; private set; }

    public IColumnBuilder<TModel> Bind<TItem>(Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> propertySelector)
    {
        // Reset the properties. This is needed because they are not cleared automatticly. It's not a new instance which is created.
        CssClass = null;

        GridBuilderReference.ColumnBuilders.Add(this);

        return this;
    }

    public IColumnBuilder<TModel> WithCss(string className)
    {
        CssClass = className;

        return this;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

First of all, it's my first fluent interface implementation so if it's not the good approach please point me in the right direction.

The situation:

- When I'm constructing the grid, I pass in an action to bind the columns and those columns are fluent again as well, (I can add a class on a column for example). Now, to render those, I tought it was a good idea to hold a reference to all IColumnBuilder instances in my IGridBuilder, so that in my GridBuilder renders method I can do something like

  // Rendering before the columns.

  foreach (var c in myColumns)
  {
      c.Render();
  }

  // Rendering after the columns.

Therefore, I've created a list in the GridBuilder that will contain all the ColumnBuilders.
When I execute a WithColumns, my GridBuilder object (this) is passed, and then in ColumnBuilder, on each Bind() function I add the ColumnBuilder object to the passed reference.

But this has a strange behaviour (for example, the list containing the ColumnBuilders, does all match the properties of the last ColumnBuilder executed).

Comment: Are the comments necessary? They add a lot of noise. Could you clearly show where you are experiencing a problem - perhaps giving a use case with the expected/actual results?

Comment: @DaveParsons at a guess the problem is that `.WithColumns` only creates a single column builder which is then bound multiple times, overwriting the previous binding? I think `.WithColumns` should provide a `IColumnBuilderFactory` which has a method `Add` or `New`. Either that or `Bind` should be a weird extension method of column that allows the column to be null and creates a new one

Comment: So, I've removed the comments in the code and explained a bit more in detail. Hope that helps. @JamesBarrass Would you mind providing a little example for the factory you mention? After inspecting my own code again, it seems that you're right with the story you tell, but I don't see directly how I could solve this issue in particular. So it would be great if you could provide a little example. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

```
public class ColumnBuilderFactory<TModel> : IColumnBuilderFactory<TModel>
{
    #region Constructors

    public ColumnBuilderFactory(IGridBuilder<TModel> gridBuilder)
    {
        gridBuilderReference = gridBuilder;
    }

    #endregion

    #region IColumnBuilderFactory Members

    private IGridBuilder<TModel> gridBuilderReference { get; private set; }

    internal IList<IColumnBuilder<TModel>> Columns {get; private set; }

    public IColumnBuilder<TModel> New()
    {
        var column = new ColumnBuilder(gridBuilderReference);
        Columns.Add(column);
        return column;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

and GridBuilder `WithColumns` becomes

```
public IGridBuilder<TModel> WithColumns(Action<IColumnBuilderFactory<TModel>> bindAllColumns)
{
    var factory = new ColumnBuilderFactory<TModel>(this);
    bindAllColumns(factory);

    foreach(var column in factory)
    {
        this.ColumnBuilders.Add(column );
    }        

    return this;
}
```

This has the usage

```
RenderedOutput = HtmlHelper.GridFor(Model)
.WithColumns(columnFactory =>
{
    columnFactory.New().Bind(x => x.Name)
        .WithCss("inline");
    columnFactory.New().Bind(x => x.Age)
        .WithCss("inline fixed right");
})
.Render();
```

**Method 2**

The alternative does much the same by cheating and ignoring this (using the FluentAPI to replace it), basically it's the same as your current usage but `Bind` becomes

```
public IColumnBuilder<TModel> Bind<TItem>(Expression<Func<TModel, TItem>> propertySelector)
{
    var builder = new ColumnBuilder<TModel>(GridBuilderReference);

    GridBuilderReference.ColumnBuilders.Add(builder);

    return builder;
}
```

It relies on the GC tidying up the first(useless) instance

so.....

```
RenderedOutput = HtmlHelper.GridFor(Model)
.WithColumns(column =>
{
//column at this point isn't used, it's only there to avoid a NullReferenceException on the first call to Bind
    column
.Bind(x => x.Name)
//Bind has returned a new ColumnBuilder to play with so the next call will be on the new instance
        .WithCss("inline");
//Again this is just so we can make the next bind call
    column
//Again bind replaces the previous instance with a new one so we won't overwrite Name with this call
.Bind(x => x.Age)
//This now sets the css on the new ColumnBuilder we just created for Age
        .WithCss("inline fixed right");
})
.Render();
```

Example Console App showing Method 2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var master = FluentHelper.GridFor(new Model())
            .WithColumns(column =>
                {
                    column.Bind(x => x.Name)
                        .WithCSS("inline");
                    column.Bind(x => x.Age)
                        .WithCSS("inline fixed right");
                });

            foreach(var c in master.children)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Binding.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(c.CSS);
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }

    class Model
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
    }

    class GridBuilder<T>
    {
        public GridBuilder<T> WithColumns(Action<ColumnBuilder<T>> bindAllColumns)
        {
            bindAllColumns(new ColumnBuilder<T>(this));

            return this;
        }

        public List<ColumnBuilder<T>> children = new List<ColumnBuilder<T>>();
    }

    class ColumnBuilder<T>
    {
        private GridBuilder<T> grid;

        public string Binding;
        public string CSS;

        public ColumnBuilder(GridBuilder<T> grid)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.grid = grid;
        }

        public void WithCSS(string css)
        {
            this.CSS = css;
        }

        public ColumnBuilder<T> Bind<TItem>(Expression<Func<T, TItem>> propertySelector)
        {
            var builder = new ColumnBuilder<T>(grid);

            builder.Binding = (propertySelector.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;

            grid.children.Add(builder);

            return builder;
        }
    }

    static class FluentHelper
    {

        internal static GridBuilder<T> GridFor<T>(T model)
        {
            return new GridBuilder<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've looked at your code, and there are a few issues with your approach by using the fluent API. First of all, I think to the columnbuilders you need to add "builder" instead of "this". And secondly, it's not working correctly anymore now, because adding a css class on it does rely on this and not on the created builder instance. Could you advice on that one as well. I think the first approach is working, but I prefer the syntax which I'm having right now, without the usage of the "New()" on the ColumnBinder due to the factory sitting in between.

Comment: Also, when I'm using your factory, your foreach loop isn't working because factory is not IEnumerable. So there's another bug.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the code a bit and now it's working. The general idea was good. Can you just provide me the ajusted code to work without the factory. As I like that syntax more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Complexity, You're right in the second method it should be `builder`. Note that builder becomes **this** on any subsequent calls which are not `Bind` so the method bind is actually separating your columns. Apologies for the slightly broken code I wrote it off the top of my head without my IDE so I suspected there might be a few bugs in it

Comment: There are a couple, but it's working with some modification. What do you mean with the this reference in your second method, because right now it's not very clear.

Comment: @Complexity I've tried to clarify what is happening in the second usage scenario with comments

Comment: But, the WithCss method in the COlumnBuilder changed the values of this.css, but that doesn't change the value of builder.css or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Complexity, you're missing it :) this is the the current instance, but in a FluentAPI the current instance is the return value of the previous API call, which after `Bind` becomes **builder**. So if you call `WithCSS` after calling `Bind` then within the `WithCSS` method **this == builder**

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this out. Appreciate your help.

Comment: I've looked at your code a bit more in detail, and it seems that there is an issue when I don't want to use the factory. The first call (binding a column) does work, however the WithCss is not properly functioning anymore. since I'm modifying the css property after I've added the builder to the grid: 'GridBuilderReference.ColumnBuilders.Add(builder);'. Any advice on how I could sove that particular issue?

Comment: @Complexity, it shouldn't matter when you add the *reference* to the builder to the grid. You can still modify the instance properties as long as you hold the reference (which is until you call bind again). The only time `.WithCss` won't work is before the first call to bind

Comment: That's very strange, because I doesn't seem to work here. I'll try again later and come back to you if I have any additional quetions if you don't mind?

Comment: Btw, I've marked your answer as the accepted one. It was and still is, a great explanation on how to solve my problem.

Comment: Ok, I've tested a bit further down the road and I'm very sorry but it doesn't seem to work. And I assumes that's because me WithCss is a method and not a property. With the method I'm just setting a property on this object, but for some reason it's not reflected in my reference in the GridBuilder, I don't know what, but it seems that this is the behaviour. Could you have a look again? I would really like this code to be working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Complexity I've added an example console app

Comment: Thanks for your nice explanation. I've double checked your code with mine and I know which mistake I made. In the 'Bind()' method of the ColumnBuilder, in the end, I returned this object instead of the newly created builder object. So that solved my issue. I wish I could upvote your answer multiple times. Thanks again :-)